# Finding the parametric and vector forms of the line is perpendicular to two lines

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Finding the parametric and vector forms of the line is perpendicular to lines $(4t,1+2t,3t)$ and $(−1+s,−7+2s,−12+3s)$

And passes through the point of the intersection of two lines

A vector perpendicular to these lines is $$v = (4, 2, 3) \times (1, 2, 3) = [0, -9, 6]$$

How would I write the vector / parametric form?

Comment: Just about a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1470013/265466, with the addition that you have to compute the intersection point. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/988298/265466.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have found the direction vector $\vec v$ for the perpendicular line, now we need the intersection point $P_0$ to determine the parametric equation

$$P(t)=P_0+t\vec v$$

Comment: $[x, y, z] = [4,2,3] + t[0,-9,6]$?

Comment: There is a problem with the intersection point. Indeed for $t = 1$ we obtain $(4,3,3)$ and for $s=5$ we have $(4,3,3)$.